# does a summoned monster really have just one HP?

Tags: dungeon-world

I was looking at the wizard spell summon monster. It states the summoned monster has 1 HP. Doesn't that mean that it will die really easily? I guess the "Its bond to your plane is strong: +2 HP for each level you have" makes it usable if you pick that.

Comment: What's the question, here?  Are you asking if summoned monsters have a minimum of 1 max hp or if summoned monsters die very easily or if they are unusable on account of how easily they die?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the spell is very flexible. It's not just for summoning combat chumps.

The ***base*** creature is something small and weak. That's good! It means that if what you need is an tiny rat, not a big tiger, the spell is still useful.

If you need a combat critter, pick your 1d6 extra features appropriately: the extra HP, extra damage, +2 STR (for H&S), maybe a useful feature like tough hide or poison. What features you choose determines what actual monster results from the spell:

> The GM will tell you the type of monster you get based on the traits you select.

But if you need an owl to spy for you, pick flight and night vision instead.

Comment: Ok. That’s the trick there.